# Import the html link automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

B1 = https://g10oal.com/match/a03716cc-adf5-4818-949d-7dd2cc3cbe59/odds#hdc
B2 = https://g10oal.com/match/863a7390-eb42-48a5-bca4-45aa7a92b1f0/odds#hdc
.
.
.
B10 = https://g10oal.com/match/ef07412e-61b6-4f2a-b93a-8c9d8b1b056/odds#hdc

I want to write the macro to get B1 to B10's URL table

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var blankSyntaxA = 'ImportHtml("';
var Link1 = spreadsheet.getRange('B1');
var blankSyntaxB = '", "table", 4)';  
var liveSyntax = blankSyntaxA + Link + blankSyntaxB;

spreadsheet.getRange('L1').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula(liveSyntax);
```

But the L1 shown =>`=ImportHtml("Range", "table", 4)`, which is not the webpage table's content.

How can i put the Range become B1 URL?

I was changed the scrip as follow. Now, i face the problem should be:

1) L1 always get B1 Link which cannot get B2, B3, B4.
2) F1 to K5 data was same.

I suppose the output should be:

First Loop

1) L1 get B1 Link table

2) F1=N2, G1=P2, H1=O2 < EndPt

3) I1=N+LastRow, J1=P+LastRow, K1=H+LastRow

Second Loop

1) L1 get B2 Link table

2) F2=N2, G2=P2, H2=O2

3) I2=N+LastRow, J2=P+LastRow, K2=H+LastRow

Thirt Loop

1) L1 get B3 Link table

2) F3=N2, G3=P2, H3=O2 < EndPt

3) I3=N+LastRow, J3=P+LastRow, K3=H+LastRow

Comment: Try `var Link1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').getValue()`; You're not specifying the sheet or getting the value.  A range is not a value.

Comment: Thanks for Cooper Reply. I was changed the scrip as follow. Now, i face the problem should be:

1) L1 always get B1 Link which cannot get B2, B3, B4.
2) F1 to K5 data was same.

I suppose the output should be:
First Loop
1) L1 get B1 Link table
2) F1=N2, G1=P2, H1=O2 < EndPt
3) I1=N+LastRow, J1=P+LastRow, K1=H+LastRow < StartPt

Second Loop
1) L1 get B2 Link table
2) F2=N2, G2=P2, H2=O2 < EndPt
3) I2=N+LastRow, J2=P+LastRow, K2=H+LastRow

Thirt Loop
1) L1 get B3 Link table
2) F3=N2, G3=P2, H3=O2 < EndPt
3) I3=N+LastRow, J3=P+LastRow, K3=H+LastRow < StartPt

Comment: I don't know why my reply deleted my ENTER.

Comment: Try to keep your comments a little simpler.  If you need to add a lot of text then add it to your question and please indent your code (you can use control-k).

Comment: I was added to the question. Please help to solve my problem.

Comment: symbol is only one value so using getValues() makes no sense.  symbol.length will always be 1.  Perhaps you meant something likes this `var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();var symbol = sh.getRange('B1').getValue();var destRange = sh.getRange('L1').setValue('=ImportHtml("' + symbol + '", "table", 4)');`

Comment: Thanks Cooper.
How can make the symbol be a loop? Because the Column B have different Link which i want L1 show B1, B2, B3 one by one.
`symbol = sh.getRange('B1').getValue()
.
.
.
symbol = sh.getRange('B2').getValue()
.
.
.
symbol = sh.getRange('B3').getValue()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it. vA[i][1] is column B vA[i][11] is column L.

```
function assembleCellFormula(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    vA[i][11]=Utilities.formatString('=ImportHtml("%s","table",4)',vA[i][1]);
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

You could also do it with something like this:

```
function assembleCellFormula(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col2=sh.getRange('B1:B10');
  var col11=sh.getRange('L1:L10');
  var vA=col2.getValues();
  var vB=col11.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    vB[i][0]=Utilities.formatString('=ImportHtml("%s","table",4)',vA[i][0]);
  }
  col11.setValues(vB);
}
```

> Note: I did not test these so they may need some debugging to work. Utilities.formatString is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate-args)

Comment: Thanks Copper
I am using the last script which you provided.
L1, L2...also shown the link.

My final goal should be:
B1 stored the Link1, <L1> get B1 link table and copy some data to F1
B2 stored the Link2, <L1> get B2 link table and copy some data to F2. One by one....How can i do that?